# Powershell CreateFromDirectory Process cannot access file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, server, windows-server-2012

I have massive 500GB index files on a Windows Server 2012R2 which are being constantly updated by an application.

I have to zip the file using PowerShell, but when I try to zip it using the following snippet of code I get this exception:

> Exception calling "CreateFromDirectory" with "4" argument(s): "The process cannot access the file 'E:\Program Files (x86)\Application Folder\File\Status.FCS' because it is being used 
>   by another process."

```
$zip = "E:\Folder\File.zip"
$can = "E:\Program Files (x86)\Application Folder\File

Import-Module AWSPowerShell

# functions
function ZipFiles( $zipfilename, $sourcedir )
{
    Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
    $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourcedir,
    $zipfilename, $compressionLevel, $false)
}

ZipFiles $zip $can
```

I don't have any issues if I am compressing the files using the Windows GUI, but problem seems to happen only when I am using a PowerShell script. Also if I stop application services, the PowerShell script works fine (which I can't do in prod environment).

One of the solution is to copy folder with 500Gb of index and compress it (which should work) but I don't have enough disk space on my Windows server to do so.

So is there any solution to compress the file while it is write locked using PowerShell script?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to write your own enumeration of the directory, read each file as a `IO.FileStream` with `[IO.FileShare]::ReadWrite` flag that allows opening files used by other processes (except when locked for reading explicitly but that's not the case here since the GUI works) and write to a new `IO.Compression.ZipArchive`. Maybe you'll be able to find existing libraries/examples.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a different directory for the zip file : `[System.IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory($inPath)`
so

```
Function ZipFiles( $zipFileName, $pathTarget )
{
   Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
   # Emplacement de sortie
   [System.IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory($inPath)
   $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
   [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($pathTarget, $zipFileName, $compressionLevel, $false)

}
```